# Loading jQuery script after Angular route / view loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am just learning AngularJS. I currently have a simple SPA that loads two containers, switching one after another depending on the URL.

Navigation Links
- Casefilm
- Videos

Using basic Angular Routing, I am able to load both successfully. However, one of the pages (videos.php) contain a slideshow script that is based on jQuery and a simple Bootstrap modal to load fullscreen Youtube videos. When this page is called, Angular loads the view but for some reason does not recognize the jQuery instance.

Here's my Videos view code:

```
<div id="videos" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="video-carousel">
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sbLR4m4Wxl0"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UMjZ2Nf-WUs"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/27FNIjyBfsI"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/J1G_KGv5aIk"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/twgSNs-HxWk"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/d1Yte1intKE"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IAxbbhB4n1w"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LjrH8T9VfZU"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qivmHtbeWec"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
     <div><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-thevideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0d9nYoS8tlw"><img ng-src="assets/images/thumb10.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- #videos -->

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div>
          <iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my app.js:

```
var humanApp = angular.module('humanApp', ['ngRoute']);

humanApp.controller('HumanCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http){
  http.get('videos.json').success(function(data){
    scope.videos = data;
  });
}]);

humanApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/casefilm',
        {
          controller: 'HumanCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'assets/partials/casefilm.php'
        })
    .when('/videos',
        {
          controller: 'HumanCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'assets/partials/videos.php'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/casefilm' });
});

humanApp.directive('slickSlider',function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $(element).slick(scope.$eval(attrs.slickSlider));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And lastly, this is what is on my index.php before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/slick.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#video-carousel").slick(
      {
        infinite: true, 
        dots: true, 
        arrows: false, 
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    );

    $(function(){
      $('iframe').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

      // If you want to keep full screen on window resize
      $(window).resize(function(){
        $('iframe').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
      });
    });

    function autoPlayYouTubeModal(){
      var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
      trigger.click(function() {
        var theModal = $(this).data( "target" ),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr( "data-thevideo" ), 
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC+"?autoplay=1;rel=0;html5=1" ;
        $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal+' button.close').click(function () {
          $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        });   
      });
    }

    autoPlayYouTubeModal();
  });
</script>
```

Summary:

- Angular routing works.
- jQuery is not working when my Video view is called.

Question:

- Am I missing something?
- Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) . in requirejs you can set dependency.

Here is some example given :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // override require function, with it's "rebinded" version
            window.require = require.bind(this, {
                // set baseUrl once and for all
                'baseUrl': '/some/absolute/path/and_another_one/'
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "myModule1.js",
                "myModule2.js"
            ], function($myModule1, $myModule2) {
                // do something here...
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find more at :

> http://www.angrycoding.com/2011/09/managing-dependencies-with-requirejs.html

Comment: Thanks, but how do I integrate this on my current app? Can you explain this further using my code?

Comment: Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/qdadOSWEYU8AUYGUgcDB. I just copy pasted what I have in some of my files. I did not take the time to make it work there.

Comment: http://www.startersquad.com/angularjs-requirejs/ here is some simple example which will help you to wrap your code with requirejs .

Comment: Isn't this a little too complex for a simple page like mine? I only need to make my current plugin and jQuery on load work with the loaded Angular view.

(1) I have a jQuery slideshow plugin called Slick, (2) I need to manipulate the elements on videos.php which is a view of Angular. (3) When switched to that page, it does not recognize the jQuery script from index.php nor does the Slick js path.